# Creating a Dynamic iCalendar Feed

Tags: c#, web-applications, icalendar

I am looking for a means to generate a iCalendar feed using .Net , atm I am using the DDay library to generate the iCal file and write it to the response.

The problem with this is if I feed the URL to outlook it says that it is a invalid ics file.

I have tried various routes including :

Using MVC routing so that the link contains a .ics extension.
Changing the Mime Type so that it is Text/Calendar.

One observation I have found is that if I navigate to the URL in a browser a valid iCal file is generated and is imported into Outlook correctly. Secondly if I take that exactly file and host it via IIS as static content , Outlook picks it up as a valid file.

The problem is that I need to generate a Dynamic feed and seem to have run out of things to try and get this working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem in my case was that the default asp.net auth was blocking outlook because it was not authenticating , once a exception was added to the web.config , the URL loaded correctly in outlook

Comment: How did you add the exception to the web.config?